# Avoid Nested NavigationTabView

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm struggling with something apparently simple.
I have a view that arrives with a navigationLink since is not the primary view of my app. In this view i have some links that sends to this view but with different data's. I want to nest those links, but now i'm reciving the double tab View on top. How can I change this? I knwo that I need to toogle the Navigation bar on the second view, but my second view is actually the same view but with different data.

Here's the code

```
/// ContentView
struct MatchListView: View {
   var namespace: Namespace.ID
   @ObservedObject var dataViewModel = DataViewModel()
   @State private var selectedMatchID: Int?
   @State private var selectedDayIndex: Int = 0
   @State private var headerHeight: CGFloat = 0
   @State private var didFinishFirst = false

   var body: some View {
       ForEach(data.leagues, id: \.id) { league in
           VStack {
               leagueHeader(league: league)
               ForEach(league.matches, id: \.id) { match in
                   matchRow(match: match, namespace: namespace)
               }
            }
           .foregroundStyle(Color.textAccent)
           .background(Color.bgSecondaryAccent)
           .cornerRadius(10)
       }
   }
}

func matchRow(match: Match, namespace: Namespace.ID) -> some View {
   NavigationLink(destination: MatchDetailsView(namespace: namespace, matchID: match.id, homeTeamName: match.home.name, awayTeamName: match.away.name)) { 
       Text("go to match \(match.id)")
   }
}


/// MatchDetails View
struct MatchDetailsView: View {
   NavigationView {  
       List {
           ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
               HighlightsView(matchViewModel: matchViewModel)
               MOTMView(matchViewModel: matchViewModel)
               EventsView(matchViewModel: matchViewModel)
               MatchStats(matchViewModel: matchViewModel)
               MatchTopPlayers(matchViewModel: matchViewModel)                       
               TeamFormView(matchViewModel: matchViewModel)
           }        
       }
   }
   .toolbar {
       ShareLink(item: URL(string: "https://maykmayk.github.io/Balun/#/match-details/\(matchID)")!) {
           Label("", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
       }
       Button {
           // action
       } label: {
           Image(systemName: "bell")
       }
       Button {
           // action
        } label: {
           Image(systemName: "star")
       }
   }
   .toolbarRole(.editor)
   .tint(Color(.textAccent))
}


/// TeamformView
struct TeamFormView: View {

   var body: some View {
       NavigationLink(destination: MatchDetailsView(namespace: namespace, matchID: getMatchID(from: match.linkToMatch ?? ""), homeTeamName: match.home?.name ?? "", awayTeamName: match.away?.name ?? "")) {
           Text(match.score ?? "")
               .foregroundColor(.white)
               .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .medium))
               .padding(.horizontal, 5)
               .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
               .background(
                   match.resultString == "W" ? Color.greenAccent :
                   match.resultString == "L" ? Color.redAccent :
                   match.resultString == "D" ? Color.gray.opacity(0.5) :
                   Color.black
               )
               .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6, style: .continuous))
       }
   }
}
```

My Preview:
https://ibb.co/gRHcDSb
What I want:
https://ibb.co/W6ysFYn

Comment: Hello italian friend, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it is easier to try it out?

Comment: just uploaded an example code

Comment: Senti, se vuoi ti passo il mio telegram che facciamo prima. Prova a copiare e incollare quel codice in un progetto vuoto e vedi quanti errori ti da. Sembra che la gente qui scriva il codice direttamente nell'editor di Stack Overflow. Comunque, con le modifiche che ho fatto a me la navigazione non crea due navigation bar. Però il mio codice è pesantemente editato per correggere tutti gli errori che c'erano.

Comment: Ho capito il perchè comunque... Hai due NavigationView annidate. Devi usare una sola NavigationView (che comunque, ammenochè non voglia supportare iOS 15 o precedenti, dovresti usare NavigationStack). Quindi rimuovi le NavigationView nelle viste figlie e lascia solo quella nella vista più in alto e dovrebbe funzionare tutto.

Comment: grazie Mat, è un errore stupido me ne rendo conto! se vuoi passarmi il tuo TG comunque fai pure e grazie mille ancora per il tuo supporto!

Comment: Il mio nick di telegram è MatBu95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting it as an answere here.
The issue you are facing is due to nested NavigationView's. That's why you are seeing more then one navigation bar when navigating to a new screen.
**Tip:** unless you are supporting iOS 15 or older, consider using NavigationStack.

You can edit your code to resemble this:

```
NavigationView {
    MatchListView(namespace: namespace)
}
```

MatchListView can stay as it was I guess:

```
struct MatchListView: View {
   var namespace: Namespace.ID
   //@ObservedObject var dataViewModel = DataViewModel()
   @State private var selectedMatchID: Int?
   @State private var selectedDayIndex: Int = 0
   @State private var headerHeight: CGFloat = 0
   @State private var didFinishFirst = false

   var body: some View {
       ForEach(["Leage 1", "League 2"], id: \.self) { league in
           VStack {
               
               ForEach(["Match 1", "Match 2"], id: \.self) { match in
                   NavigationLink(destination: MatchDetailsView()) {
                          Text("go to match ID")
                    }
               }
            }
           .foregroundStyle(.black)
           .background(.fill)
           .cornerRadius(10)
       }
   }
}
```

Remove the other NavigationView from here:

```
struct MatchDetailsView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        /// Remove this NavigationView and others if parents views already have one
        //NavigationView {
            List {
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    //               HighlightsView(matchViewModel: matchViewModel)
                    //               MOTMView(matchViewModel: matchViewModel)
                    //               EventsView(matchViewModel: matchViewModel)
                    //               MatchStats(matchViewModel: matchViewModel)
                    //               MatchTopPlayers(matchViewModel: matchViewModel)
                    TeamFormView()
                }
            }
            
            .toolbar {
                
            }
            .toolbarRole(.editor)
            .tint(.accentColor)
        //}
    }
    
}
```

I hope this has worked well for you and the explaination was clear!